# Java Implementation of SpeedyFX Hashing Alogrithm

Tags: java, hash

According to this paper [Extremely Fast Text Feature Extraction for Classification and Indexing](http://www.scribd.com/doc/5557479/Extremely-Fast-Text-Feature-Extraction-for-Classification-and-Indexing) SpeedyFX is a very fast hashing algorithm.

I would like to know if someone have the Java implementation of this algorithm.

Comment: The version the paper authors implemented was in Java. The code is right in the Appendices.

Comment: I have implemented the algorithm as described in the paper but I faced many problems.

Answer (score 2):

The original implementation is *a bit* flawed in regards of UTF-8 and Unicode handling. It only considers the [Unicode Plane 0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29#Basic_Multilingual_Plane), while there actually are many word characters in Planes 1 and 2 (and, as of 12/28/2012, no word characters in Planes 3-16).

FWIW, I have [implemented the SpeedyFx algorithm in C](https://github.com/creaktive/Text-SpeedyFx/blob/master/SpeedyFx.xs#L127), as a part of Perl module [Text::SpeedyFx](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aSpeedyFx). Worked really great for me for both UTF-8 and ISO 8859-1 encoded strings.